# Filtering SelectListItem using a string array.-mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have tow variables in my mvc application .that is shown below

```
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableAgents { get; set; }
   public string[] AvailableAgentSelected { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AgentsNotselected{ get; set; }
```

The AvailableAgents  contains  all agent list items. and AvailableAgentSelected is a string array it contains values of selected agents only..

From the above data how can i store the agents who are not selected to AgentsNotselected (means,select all agent list items whose values are not in AvailableAgentSelected ) . I want an efficeiant way to do it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last property has two types, I asume it's IEnumerable.
I didn't try it, but this should work, although the "efficient" part is questionable.

```
AgentsNotselected = AvaliableAgents.Where(a => !AvailableAgentSelected.Contains(a.Value));
```

Comment: i tried this. but not working.Its just assignin value of AvaliableAgents to AgentsNotselected .i think the where part is not working